# Power Query - function with two parameters as new column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have below function which fetches data from a url with two parameters

```
let Source = (MyItem as text, PageNumber as number) =>
let
        Headers = [
        #"Content-Type" = "application/json",
        ],

        category = "public",
        pageSize = 100,
        timeout = 0,

        requestBody = "{""item"": """ & MyItem & """,""category"": """ & category & """,""page"": " & Text.From(PageNumber) & ",""row"": " & Text.From(pageSize) & ",""timeout"": " & Text.From(timeout) & "}",

            URL = "https://website.com/item/",

            JsonData = Json.Document(Web.Contents(URL, [Headers=Headers, Content=Text.ToBinary(requestBody)]))
        in
            JsonData

  in 
  Source
```

I have a table which contains items

I would like to add a custom column to the table with Items to get web content. When I use the below code, I only get page 1 of the results, I don't know how to loop through pages with results, to get results from page 2 as well.

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "GetWebData", each GetWebData([Item], 1))
```

I also tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "GetWebData", each GetWebData([Item], 1)&GetWebData([Item], 2))
```

I also tried creating another table with pages and pass it as a parameter, but I am only able to select items from one table when I invoke function when adding new column.

Comment: This will probably be helpful https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/

Comment: @horseyride is right once again. Try making a function that uses List.Generate to get all pages of results for a specific item and combine them together. Then use that function in your `Table.AddColumn` instead.